# Serviceworker subscription working in firefox but not in Chrome. Throws error: "Registration failed - no Service Worker""

Tags: node.js, reactjs, service-worker

I'm trying to setup a service worker for recieving push notifications from a nodejs backend into react. The following code works in Firefox, but Chrome throws the error "Registration failed - no Service Worker". The serviceworker itself seems to be working, but the inclusion of the subscription call on the pushManager throws the error. Does anyone know what is wrong, or do you need more information?

```
const checkSupport = () => {
  if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator) || !('PushManager' in window)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service.js', { scope: '/' });
  await navigator.serviceWorker.ready; // Waits for the serviceworker to be ready
  return registration;
};

const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
  const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
  if (permission !== 'granted') {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

// urlB64ToUint8Array is a magic function that will encode the base64 public key
// to Array buffer which is needed by the subscription option
const urlBase64ToUint8Array = (base64String: string) => {
  const padding = '='.repeat((4 - (base64String.length % 4)) % 4);
  const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');

  const rawData = atob(base64);
  const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
    outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return outputArray;
};

const installServiceWorker = async (team: number, semester: number) => {
  try {
    // Check browser compatability and notification permission
    if (!checkSupport() || !(await requestNotificationPermission())) return;
    // Register serviceworker
    const registration = await registerServiceWorker();

    registration.showNotification('Hello notification!');

    // Subscribe the user to notifications
    const publicVAPID =
      '<String>';
    const applicationServerKey = urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVAPID);
    const subscription = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey
    });  

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(new Error(error));
  }
};

export default installServiceWorker;
```

The serviceworker looks like this (and seems to be working):

```
console.log('Hello from serviceworker');

self.addEventListener('activate', async () => {
  console.log('activated');
});

self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  const data = event.data.json();

  self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: 'Yay it works!'
  });
});
```

This is the error
[image: Console error]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that the reason the serviceworker wasn't working, was that create-react-app (which I bootstrapped my app with) includes its own serviceworker. When I remove the call to that, my own custom serviceworker started working.